# How to implement a Hover state for an Object

Tags: hover

I have a code for a menu which is implemented for Click.

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;

        var loc = window.location.pathname;

        var filename = loc.match(/([^\/]+)(?=\.\w+$)/)[0];

         console.log("sssss" + $(this).attr("id"));
         obj.dd.on('click', function(event){

            console.log($(this).attr("id"));
            if(!($(this).hasClass("active")) && ( $(this).attr("id")) === filename) {
                 console.log("Hiding");
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        }); 
    }
}

$(function() {

   var dd1 = new DropDown( $('#value') );
    var dd2 = new DropDown( $('#diagnostics') );
    var dd3 = new DropDown( $('#design') );
    var dd4 = new DropDown( $('#delivery') );

    //$('.wrapper-dropdown-5').on('click', function(e){ console.log(e); });

    $(document).click(function() {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

If you see  **obj.dd.on('click', function(event){**, that is where the click action is being intercepted. But I want to implement hover state, and to my surprise, it is not working, I tried using hover, mouseover and mouseout there, but nothing works. Only click is working.

Do you have any idea what might be the problem or how could I  implement Hover in this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: have you changed all the **click** to **hover** ?

Comment: Yes. It is very strange, but it didn't work. Actually it did work before but suddenly it stopped working.